# Which is the best ubuntu version for my laptop dell inspiron 3521

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, ati, dell

Following is my laptop configuration

```
Model : Dell Inspiron 3521
Processor : i3 third Generation
Ram : 4 GB
Hard Disk : 500GB
Graphics Cards: Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 4000 HD, ATI Readon HD 87XX Series.
```

I tried installing Ubuntu 13.10 , every thing works fine except my hybrid ati graphics card.And when i installed 12.04 LTS nothing was working(wifi,ethernet,sound etc).

So please tell me which Ubuntu will be best for my laptop ....

Comment: You should try the latest Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS 64bit  http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: There is no reason to assume any of the operating systems is "best". Please download the live dvd and see for yourself. I would start with 14.04 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Ubuntu **14.04**  ([LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)).

Nvidia graphic card is running fine in Xubuntu 14.04.

Hope 14.04 can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link and see the certified hardware for Ubuntu.

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/make/Dell/?category=Desktop&category=Laptop

I hope this helps.

Regards,